# Неправильная работа метода time.sleep. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Помогите пожалуйста.
Делаю игру на Python с помощью библиотеки Pygame.

```
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x_1 > 20:
    while speed_1 < 6:
        speed_1 += 1
        sleep(0.6)
    x_1 -= speed_1
```

В этом промежутке кода, персонаж должен плавно разгоняться.
Переменная `speed_1`, отвечает за **скорость**.
По идее когда зажата кнопка, он сначала бежит **медленно**, потом за несколько секунд **ускоряется** и доходит до **максимальной скорости**. Но вместо этого персонаж просто **стоит** пока цикл не **достигнет максимальной скорости**, а потом бежит на **максимальной скорости**.

Comment: Какие строчки кода отвечают за "бежит"? time.sleep(), разумеется, работает правильно. Не надо сваливать на здоровую голову.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте разберем, что делает ваш код:

1. Проверяем условия(нажата левая стрелка и переменная x_1 больше 20
2. Ждем до тех пор, пока скорость не станет равна 6 (т.е. максимальной)
3. Из `x_1` вычитаем `speed_1`

Скорее всего, это условие у вас в бесконечном цикле. Если так, то ваша ошибка кроется во втором шаге. Замените `while` на `if`, чтобы программа не ждала, а сравнивала скорость и успевала сдвинуть персонажа. А чтобы рывками не двигался ваш персонаж, уменьшите задержку до примерно 0.06 секунд, т.е. код должен получится такой:

```
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x_1 > 20:
        if speed_1 < 6:
            x_1 -= speed_1
            time.sleep(0.06)
            speed_1 += 1
        else:
            x_1 -= speed_1
```

Comment: Извините, не работает. Тоже самое, но персонаж немного двигается а не просто стоит.

Comment: @loganag исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вообще избавиться от `sleep` вот так:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

KEY_REACTION_SLEEP = timedelta(milliseconds=600)  # 0.6 секунды

# Где-то чуть выше основного цикла объявляем такую переменную
last_move_key_reaction = datetime(1901, 1, 1)

if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x_1 > 20:
    if speed_1 < 6:
        now = datetime.now()
        if now >= (last_move_key_reaction + KEY_REACTION_SLEEP):
            speed_1 += 1
            last_move_key_reaction = now
    x_1 -= speed_1
```